# HTML5 waiting event equivalent in MediaElement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

We are building a video solution which gives some heuristics based on buffering, latency and wait time etc.
I see HTML5 has and event called "waiting" which is triggered when every player is buffering. I like MediaElement.js given its simplicity and power to handle multiple formats. However I don't see a "waiting" event there in MediaElement.js at their site. I wonder what is the alternative or is there any specific reason this event was left out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative using "progress" and "timeupdate". Maintain a state value which sets to playing when timeupdate event gets called and buffering when progress event is called provided previous state was playing. That way one can measure buffering time in total.